# Hide fields from SearchForm depending on the request user groups

Tags: python, django, search-form

I have a `StockSearchForm`:

```
class StockSearchForm(CustomForm):
    component__code__icontains = forms.CharField(label=_('component code'),
                                                 required=False)
    component__name__icontains = forms.CharField(label=_('component name'),
                                                 required=False)
    component__product__icontains = forms.ChoiceField(
        label=_('product'), required=False, choices=b_choice + PRODUCT_CHOICES)
    inventory = forms.BooleanField(label=_('to inventory'), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StockSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[
            'component__code__icontains'].widget.attrs[
            'class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields[
            'component__name__icontains'].widget.attrs[
            'class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields[
            'component__product__icontains'].widget.attrs[
            'class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['inventory'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'btn pull-left'
        self.fields['inventory'].initial  = False
```

The field that is named `inventory` I only need to display it if the request user has groups "Administrator" or "Purchasing". I tried many codes that I found but neither works, can someone how to do it?

I tried doing

```
if not request.user.groups.filter(name__in["Admnistrator", "Purchasing"]).exists():
            del self.fields['inventory']
```

and even

```
self.fields['inventory'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

but nothing works for me

(I know that I'm not setting `request` as a parameter, but I tried setting it obviously even `user` as a parameter

Comment: where are you deleting the fields?

Comment: what fields? I'm not deleting nothing because I don't know how to do it @scaryhamid

Comment: you said you tried del the fields

Comment: yes because this is what I need, delete the field if the request user is not administrator or purchasing @scaryhamid

Comment: you have to do it in __init__ of the form , then pass the request to your form from your view